# Line sweep horizontal and vertical groups of points detection

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have the following image. Where I have sets of points thare are aligned horizontally and vertically. What algorithm can I use to find these sets?

is using the line sweet algorithm good idea?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I would like to clarify - do you need to detect groups of points, which belongs to the same line?

Comment: I think the example shows only the "happy case" where all the sets are disjoint. Will the sets never touch or intersect? Are they always separated by a distance which is larger than the distance between points within a set? In that case it's a simple grouping. If sets can be closer than the dist within set, or if they can intersect/overlap, then it is tricky.

Comment: Yes I need to detect groups of points @stemm

Comment: Hello @AndersForsgren:

1- Yes inter-sets distances are always greater than the intra-sets distances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general case - if you need to detect the lines on the image, or the groups of points, which located along the different lines - I'd suggest you to use [Hough transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform).

Comment: Yes I was thinking about it. and it's a simple solution Stemm?

Comment: The pros of solution, based on Hough transform - is such that you can use it "as is" for extended variant of your problem - (not only vertical and horizontal lines, non-regular gap between points etc.)